# null is not an object in getInitialState() react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react native and getting one error as 'null is not object (evaluating 'this.state.pan')'

and the code for that is :

```
getInitialState: function(){
return{
  pan : new Animated.ValueXY(),
  panResponder: PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null,{
      dx : this.state.pan.x,
      dy : this.state.pan.y
    }]),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e,gesture)
  })
}
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with bold text ?

Comment: interesting, is the `**pan : ... **` a valid syntax?

Comment: No, I just highlighted it , check new edits please @Cherniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to this.state in the 'getInitialState method. But 'this.state' only has a value after 'getInitialState' has been called. You can however do something like this.

```
getInitialState: function(){
  var panValue = new Animated.ValueXY();
  return{
    pan : panValue,
    panResponder: PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null,{
      dx : panValue.x,
      dy : panValue.y,
    }]),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e,gesture)
  })
}
}
```